# Xamarin Form: Is Google Drive File Dialog available?

Tags: xamarin, google-drive-api, printer-control-language

I have get the Android to load a file dialog for google drive after authorization. Now I have to do it on Xamarin Form but unable to find a file picker for google drive. Does google drive have a file picker for Xamarin Form.

```
public void RequestGoogleDrivePicker() {
        IntentSender intentSender = 
            Android.Gms.Drive.DriveClass.DriveApi.NewOpenFileActivityBuilder ()
                .SetMimeType (new string[] { "application/pdf" })
                .Build (GoogleApiClient);
        try { 
            StartIntentSenderForResult ( intentSender, GOOGLE_REQUESTING_OPENER_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (Android.Content.IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Google Drive file browser dialog for `Xamarin.Forms`?

Short answer: No

Longer answer: Yes, but...

1) You either use the "native" platform Drive SDKs that contain pre-build file browser dialogs for `Android` and `iOS` and do this via a Forms' [dependency service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) like you already started in the `Xamarin.Android` code in your question.

2) You skip the "native" mobile libraries, use the C# `PCL`-based Google Nugets in your Forms' project and build your own file dialog in `Forms` as there are no dialogs in these libraries as they are convenience wrappers for the Drive's REST API.

Nugets:

- Google.Apis
- Google.Apis.Auth

i.e. You can retrieve all the files in Drive, you would need to present these in a UI of your own design (`Listview`, ...), see link below for full sample:

```
IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
}
```

[Google Drive .NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet)